# Прочувствовал я таки на полную катушку то, что-с это такое на самом-то деле(,) — твоё приложение, о мой Лео-мэтр

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Прочувствовал я таки на полную катушку то, что-с это такое на самом-то деле(,) — твоё приложение, о мой Лео-мэтр

Comment: Лео, пожалуйста, уточните смысл слова "приложение", а то содержание предложения трудно понять.

Comment: Электронное таки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Прочувствовал я таки на полную катушку **то**, что-с это такое на самом-то деле, — твоё **приложение**, о мой Лео-мэтр* — подчеркнуто пояснение и поясняемое слово (полужирным), где пояснение относится к слову *то*, то есть не относится к придаточному;

*Прочувствовал я таки на полную катушку то, что-с **это** такое на самом-то деле — твоё **приложение**, о мой Лео-мэтр* — здесь поясняемое слово — *это*, к нему относится пояснение, а оно в придаточном, поэтому пряснение входит в придаточное и не отделяется от него запятой.

Зависит от автора, ставить или нет запятую. Автор решает, к какому слову отнести пояснение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, ТОЧНО укажите вид СПП для обоих случаев. Трудно понять их структуру по вашим вариантам. Грамматика и семантика меняются или нет? Я могу предположить,  что ваш ответ неверен. Но объяснение некорректно в любом случае.

Comment: Я полагаю, что вам нужно отказаться от практики МГНОВЕННЫХ ответов, особенно если речь идет о ГРАММАТИКЕ. Там много нюансов, которые даже при  ДОСТАТОЧНОМ опыте работы с темой не всегда можно понять.

Comment: Ответьте, пожалуйста, на мой комментарий.   Я думаю, вы его видели. Меня интересует: вид СПП и и семантика меняются или нет? Свой ответ я дам позже.

Comment: @Sharon Занят был. СПП с определительными отношениями. А насчет семантики сложно сказать. Но автор выбирает, какое слово пояснение должно пояснять.

Comment: Очень неопределенный ответ, там разные виды бывают. Поэтому обозначьте точнее, в том числе схему предложения назовите. В данном случае это важно  Какова роль местоимений в двух ваших ВАРИАНТАХ, что по схеме меняется. Я полагаю, что вариантов нет, но есть вопрос об изъяснительном придаточном. Но такая структура не выглядит корректно.  В любом случае в ответе это все надо обозначить. Это грамматика!

Comment: А где же схема? Хотела, чтобы автор ответ улучшил... :(